# Why ASP.NET MVC bothers to have a Default.aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

When create a new ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2008, there is a Default.aspx page by default. It has one line

> 

In its Page_Load function, it just redirects to "/" to go through the routing procedure.

```
    public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath);
        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    }
```

I tried to remove Default.aspx and it turns out that the default URI "http://localhost:2574/" is still accessible. So, why bother to have such Default.aspx?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Older versions of IIS need a startup document and it also gives you something to right-click on to get the "View in Browser" option.

Comment: what is "older version"? IIS 6?

Answer (score 6):

What's happening here, is that the Url requested (which was Default.aspx) is being re-written to the application root "/" and then transferred off of the Webform HTTP handler and onto the MvcHttpHandler. A request for "/" will match the Default route entry (show further down)... eventually sending us onto one of the route controllers.

useful link [here](http://www.58bits.com/blog/2008/09/29/asp-net-mvc-and-routing-default-aspx/)

Comment: Thanks. The link (http://www.58bits.com/blog/2008/09/29/ASPNetMVCAndRoutingDefaultaspx.aspx) actually explains that Default.aspx can be removed and it still works.

Comment: The 58bits link above is now located at http://www.58bits.com/blog/2008/09/29/asp-net-mvc-and-routing-default-aspx/