# Default.aspx page in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the Default.aspx page for in an MVC app? Does this actually execute? Does this page have anything to do with the "Default" route in the global.asax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why ASP.NET MVC bothers to have a Default.aspx file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333596/why-asp-net-mvc-bothers-to-have-a-default-aspx-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the comments at the top of Default.aspx

> Please do not delete this file. It is
>   used to ensure that ASP.NET MVC is
>   activated by IIS when a user makes a
>   "/" request to the server.

Basically, it acts as an override for the possibility of a different default page being loaded by IIS. In IIS6 if you have an index.html in the same directory as your MVC application, it can sometimes render that file instead of looking for the default blank route in your application. Default.aspx prevents that from happening.